# how can i make update, select and insert query in extbase fluid?

Tags: fluid, extbase

how can i make update, select and insert query in TYPO3 extbase fluid.
please help me by giving this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In extbase everything is handled by the database abstraction layer. You don't need to do the querys on your own unless you force extbase to that.
For Database things you have 2 files. A Domain Model and a Domain Repository. The Model contains functions like getter and setter, that simply define all fields you want to interact with.

The Repository lets you Request things like a bunch ob rows in table. However most of those unctions are done with extbase magic like findByName or findAll.

If you update, create or delete objects, you use the Repository to get an obkect or the Obkect Manager to create one. Then you can do things with the Model methos like adding a value. If you are done, you use the object Manager functions add, update, remove to send it back to db.

A select queue is pretty much getting a Object with the repository. More advanced functions can be added to the Repository if needed. Then you should read the Documentation on the query function.

Comment: Currently on Smartphone. If you need Code Examples, i can come back to that later.

Answer (score 1):

Extbase is a backport of some features of FLOW3 framework. It's an MVC framework. When you create an extension using Extension Builder, it automatically creates Domain models and repositories for you. Domain models define your data object and repositories define methods to access your data from the database and returns the applicable domain objects.

You can retrieve data using methods in `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository` like this:

```
$myRepository->findAll();
$myRepository->add($myDataModel);
$myRepository->remove($myDataModel);
```

Or your can also define your own methods to retrieve data in the repository(which extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository) of your Extension.

Check out the following references for further information: 
http://typo3.org/fileadmin/t3org/documents/information/referencesheet.pdf
http://blog.typoplanet.de/2010/01/27/the-repository-and-query-object-of-extbase/